# Notation for the set of conjonctions of two adjacent level of the levy hierarchy

Tags: logic, set-theory, predicate-logic

Let $\Sigma_n$ and $\Pi_n$ be two levels of the levy hierarchy. We consider the set of formulas $$\Gamma = \left\{ \phi \wedge \psi, \phi \in \Sigma_n, \psi \in \Pi_n \right\}$$

Is there a common name for such a $\Gamma$ ? Something like $\Sigma_n \cup \Pi_n$ or $\Sigma_n \wedge \Pi_n$ ?

Comment: I doubt there's a standard notation; using $\sum_n\land\Gamma_n$ (with an explanation) seems reasonable

Answer (score 1):

The standard notation is $\Sigma_n\wedge\Pi_n$. See for example the top of page $23$ in Arnie Miller's paper [*On the Borel Classification of the
Isomorphism Class of a Countable Model*](https://projecteuclid.org/journalArticle/Download?urlId=10.1305%2Fndjfl%2F1093870217).